# How to recover an old patition with out format?

Tags: windows-7, linux

I am using Windows 7 and Linux Ubuntu in my PC. Unfortunately, I have deleted the Linux partition from Windows 7 (it is not formatted). Linux Partition was 25 GB now and it is attached with logical drive and now it is showing 56 GB Free Space. How can I recover or separate this without formatting the Disk ?

Comment: What tools have you tried using?  How did you accidently delete the partition?

Comment: @Ramhound  since you ask him how he deleted it, i'm curious, have you found that there are different ways you can delete a partition, some of which you have recovered from, and some you haven't? or, did you find that depending on how the partition was deleted, you found different ways to recover it depending on which method it was deleted. If so, that sounds very useful, and it'd be beneficial for you to list these findings from your investigations if you ever made any.

Comment: you vould try easeus http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/  and  http://www.partition-recovery.com/download.html   i'd imagine these attempts they do are read only so shouldn't prevent further attempts.

Comment: @barlop There's a big difference between overwriting just the partition table vs. creating/resizing another partition overtop (for example). As-is this question is lacking too much information, and shows no research effort.  I'm not 100% sure if the OP wants his data back or not? If so (once that's made clear), there's MANY existing questions we could be pointing him to.

Comment: @barlop - Please read my comment again.  I didn't ask him "how" he deleted the partition I asked him an entirely different question.  Honestly, there are far to many questions on how to recover data from a deleted partition, I am not sure the reason people are suggesting software recommendations.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  well presumably if he's written over the partition then he's screwed, as with recovering files. But, I suppose the solution is(as with files), to try the recovery software and if it can't do it then maybe he wrote over it. It'd be interesting to know if some solutions are better than others for cases where part of a partition has been written over.  AT-ramhound ah I see, how he had the accident, ok, so wasn't a technical q you were asking him then.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find or assemble an external drive equal to or larger than the original drive.
2. Use a cloning app http://lifehacker.com/5839753/the-best-disk-cloning-app-for-windows to copy block by block http://www.cnet.com/news/differences-between-file-level-and-block-level-cloning/ the original drive.  This allows you to experiment without ruining the original drive.
3. Use the free, open source testdisk. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step to recover the partition
4. Once the data is recovered,  then repartition the original drive and copy the files from the second drive onto the first.

Answer (score 0):

you vould try easeus http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/  and  http://www.partition-recovery.com/download.html   i'd imagine these attempts they do are read only so shouldn't prevent further attempts with other software.

You could also try using labels next time to help avoid accidentally deleting a partition.  And it's good if the program that you delete partitions with, also shows you the data on the partition, though many don't so the clearest identifier in those cases is a label.